# Problems of security with roles in NexJs

Tags: next.js

I'm developing an aplication with Nexjs and Laravel as API, and I've 2 parts, admin dashboard and user home after successful login. In laravel I added a middleware to check the role to access to admin routes but I don't know if I manage in the best way in nextJs.

Laravel middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user && $user->role === RoleValues::ADMIN) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
```

and when the user is logged in I return:

```
"data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Mac",
            "last_name": "Carty",
            "user_name": "Mac Carty",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "role": "Admin"
        }
    }
```

So in NextJs I store the user information in a cookie

[image]

and then I have a wrapper for all admin pages

```
function AuthAdminWrapper({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const xsrfToken = Boolean(getCookie(XSRF_TOKEN));
  const isAuth = Boolean(getCookie(IS_AUTH));
  const user = getCookie(USER);
  let isAdmin = false;

  if (user && user.role === ROLES.ADMIN) {
    isAdmin = true;
  }

  if (xsrfToken && isAuth && isAdmin) {
    return children
  }

  return router.push('/');
}

export { AuthAdminWrapper }
```

My problem is the security here, is good idea to manage in this way this access to admin panel?

Comment: Yeah, it seems ok. You could also use a Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).

Comment: What happen if you have several roles and permissions, the middleware is it still good idea?